# How do I prevent wget from loading Apache directory listings in different orders?

Tags: wget

I’m trying to recursively download a directory using this command:

```
wget -r -l2 --no-parent -A "*.pdf" -nd -N -e robots=off http://…
```

The script gets executed every 15 minutes, so I want to reduce the requests as much as possible. I saw that there are a lot of requests like `?C=M;O=A` which originate from the directory order modifier buttons like *Name*, *Date* or *Size* ([example](http://howto.unixdev.net/)). How can I prevent these requests from happening?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/156045/how-to-download-with-wget-without-following-links-with-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in [an answer](https://serverfault.com/a/156057/163490) to a related question, [wget's documention](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html) says:

> Note, too, that query strings (strings at the end of a URL beginning with a question mark (‘?’) are not included as part of the filename for accept/reject rules, even though these will actually contribute to the name chosen for the local file. It is expected that a future version of Wget will provide an option to allow matching against query strings.

You will probably have to use a different tool such as [pavuk](http://www.pavuk.org/) or [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html). These two programs provide name filtering that is more robust than wget's.

As an alternative, you can download the directory using wget and filter it afterwards.

```
find . -name '*\?' -delete
# Here is a less dangerous pattern that matches the string you provided more closely:
find . -name '*\??=?;?=?' -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use httrack if you're trying to mirror a directory of *.pdf files. A command like this worked for me:

```
 % httrack http://my.server.com/dir/with/pdfs/ +mime:text/html +*.pdf --update
```

You can check out more about httrack at the following URLS:

- [Basic Users Guide](http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html)
- [Download Links](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/index.html)
- [example commands](http://www.httrack.com/html/scripting.html)
- [Blog article with additional examples](http://btmash.com/article/2011-05-25/mirroring-website-using-httrack)

I should mention one major advantage to using httrack over wget is that httrack will only download files that have changed/updated.