# wget recursive with files without extension

Tags: wildcards, wget, recursive

I'm trying to get a site with `wget`. The problem is that it:

1. Have user friendly name for the pages

   ```
   http://domain/wiki/Section/Home, 
   http://domain/wiki/Section/Not+Home
   http://domain/wiki/Section/Other+page
   ```
2. For some pages it uses query strings:

   ```
   http://domain/wiki/Section/Home?one=value&other=value
   ```
3. and for some reason maybe backup some files have an extension of *`.1`* (number from 1 - n) for example `styles.css.1`, `javascrip.js.2`

I want to do a recursive download and store it in one folder but avoid the files with queries; `Home?query` – in this case `Home`. For this I've tried `--reject` with a pattern but I can't make it work.

I can avoid extension `.1,.2,... .n` if I add a long list of numbers, but there is hopefully a better way.

This is the `wget`:

```
wget \
--page-requisites \
--no-parent \
--no-host-directories \
--no-directories \
--convert-links \
--load-cookies wget_cookies.txt --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies \
-P WikiFolders/pages/ \
-e robots=off \
-r \
--reject='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*\\?*' \
--content-disposition \
--no-check-certificate \
http://domain/wiki/Section/
```

If I run it this way I do get the site but is really slow for some content.

*Note: to avoid files with queries I tried `*\\?*` but this doesn't work.*

After I download I remove the content with:

```
find WikiFolders/pages/ -iname "*\\?*" -delete
```

but again this is really slow and I have to download lots of content.

I've thought on first exclude the `HTML` and download images, CSS and js and with other wget the HTML but since the files have no extension this doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73367/how-do-i-prevent-wget-from-loading-apache-directory-listings-in-different-orders/73371#73371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[]` notation to specify ranges of numbers and letters. Repeat for multiple.

```
*[0-9],*[0-9][0-9],*[0-9][0-9][0-9]
|____||__________||_______________|
   |       |              |
   |       |              +---------- Reject ending with 000 to 999
   |       +------------------------- Reject ending with 00 to 99
   +--------------------------------- Reject ending with 0 to 9
```

This can also be used with `--accept`.

For the query links there is no way to filter it out – however if you specify
`*\?*` the files will be deleted ***after*** they have been downloaded. So you would have to live with it using bandwidth and time for downloading, but you do not have to do a cleanup afterwards.

So, summa summarum, perhaps something like this:

```
--reject='*.[0-9],*.[0-9][0-9],*\?*'
```

If this does not suffice you would have to look into other tools like the one mentioned in *possible duplicate* link under your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid downloading the query links with the `--reject-regex "(.*)\?(.*)"` option, as explained at [Using wget but ignore url parameters - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736156/using-wget-but-ignore-url-parameters)